# Custom filter is incompatible?

Tags: c++, filter, directshow

I created a custom filter in DirectShow called decryption however when using GraphStudioNext gives me a "VFW_E_NO_ACCEPTABLE_TYPES (0x80040207)" when trying to connect the output from a MP4 into the input of my custom filter.

```
// Media Types 
const AMOVIESETUP_MEDIATYPE sudPinTypes =
{
    &MEDIATYPE_Stream,
    &MEDIASUBTYPE_NULL
};

// Pins 
const AMOVIESETUP_PIN psudPins[] =
{
    { L"Input", FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, &CLSID_NULL, L"Output", 1, &sudPinTypes },
    { L"Output", FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, &CLSID_NULL, L"Input", 1, &sudPinTypes }
};

// Filters 
const AMOVIESETUP_FILTER sudAudioVolume =
{
    &CLSID_Decryption,
    L"Decryption",
    MERIT_NORMAL,
    2,
    psudPins
};

HRESULT DecryptionFilter::CheckInputType(const CMediaType *mtIn)
{
    //Streaming
    if (mtIn->majortype != MEDIATYPE_Stream) return E_FAIL;
    if (mtIn->subtype != MEDIATYPE_NULL) return E_FAIL;

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DecryptionFilter::CheckTransform(const CMediaType *mtIn, const CMediaType *mtOut)
{
    HRESULT hr = CheckInputType(mtIn);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    if (mtIn->majortype != MEDIATYPE_Stream) return E_FAIL;
    if (mtIn->subtype != MEDIATYPE_NULL) return E_FAIL;

    return S_OK;
}
```

I debugged through GraphStudioNext and

- Source output pin's "connectionType" is PIN_CONNECTION_TYPE_STREAM
- Custom filter input pin's "connectionType" is
  PIN_CONNECTION_TYPE_OTHER

What my graph looks like:
[image: My Graph of what I'm trying to accomplish]

Properties for Source Filter and Custom Filter
[image: Properties for Source Filter and Custom Filter]

Any clue on why my filter won't connect? Thank-you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter is incompatible because it does not implement the same functionality as [File Source Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375641) you are impersonating. Specifically, you need to implement `IAsyncReader` interface.

Additionally, GDCL source is available - you can step the source and identify the exact problem with debugger.

Comment: Thanks again Roman R. So my decryption filter class would be declared as "class DecryptionFilter : public CTransformFilter, public IAsyncReader"?

Comment: Not just declared. You need to implement the interface correctly, and not on filter but on its pin. The idea is that your filter looks exactly the same way as stock file source filter, with the same interface set. So that the demultiplexer is comfortable to work with your filter instead of the standard one.